# How do I change the txtcolor within a countdown

Tags: java, countdown

I'm using this countdown to redirect to another page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var timeleft = 5;
var downloadTimer = setInterval(function(){
timeleft--;
document.getElementById("countdowntimer").textContent = ((timeleft >= 10) ? timeleft : ("0" + timeleft));
if(timeleft <= 0){
    clearInterval(downloadTimer);
    window.location.replace("url.html");
    }
},1000);

</script>
```

In html I use this for activation:

```
<span id="countdowntimer"><font color="#C0C0C0">&nbsp;</font></span>
```

How is it possible to change color of the countdown txt or even make it invisible??

Please help a java dummy.

Comment: No Need to use <font> tag, Just add some CSS to the <span> with color property, smth like : 
`#countdowntimer { color : #C0C0C0;}
`

Comment: that worked perfect for me. thanx a lot